# Can I use Activity instead of ActionbarActivity without Actionbar at Appcompat-v7?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to use Material design at under-Lolipop version of Android.

I know,

1. I must use AppTheme : Appcompat-v7
2. To use Actionbar with Appcompat-v7, I must extends ActionbarActivity

But, I don't want to use ActionbarActivity, 
because of quite diffrence with Activity and It just looks like unflexible to me, and that makes me nervous to use ActionbarActivity. It looks like just Activity class for Actionbar.

So, I think about use Toolbar(stand-alone) instead of Actionbar.
And It seems when I don't use Actionbar, then don't have to use ActionbarActivity either.

Finally, I find a solution that use below.

1. AppTheme : Appcompat-v7 21
2. Toolbar(instead of Actionbar)
3. Activity(instead of ActionbarActivity)

Did you think this is aright way? or it just doesn't make sense at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, I don't want to use ActionbarActivity, because of quite diffrence with Activity and It just looks like unflexible to me, and that makes me nervous to use ActionbarActivity. It looks like just Activity class for Actionbar.

I can't understand why it's unflexible to you to use ActionBarActivity, after all [ActionBarActivity derives from Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

And if I'm not mistaken you must derive from ActionBarActivity in order to use toolbar and all the menu, title etc stuff that was formerly used by the ActionBar itself.

That told, I think the theming part is ok, using Toolbar rather than ActionBar is also ok, the only part I don't agree with is the Activity instead of the ActionBar Activity.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks! I will use ActionbarActivity!

Comment: I just think that I don't need ActionbarActivity because I won't use Actionbar....

Comment: But to use Toolbar you must set `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` which is only available on ActionbarActivity